# How to check if record exists by searching into inner array

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this record in DB

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5759ccbcc2b503980c000143"),
   "phone": "516-425-5878",
   "orders": [
     "1338475681",
     "1891805481",
     "1891805481" 
  ] 
}
```

Here is my code.

```
$collection = $mongo_db_obj->selectCollection('scrapers', 'leads');
$data = array(
    'phone' => '516-425-5878',
    "orders" => array('$in'=>1891805481)
);

$doc = $collection->findOne($data);

dump($doc);
```

I want to check if particular `phone` and and order id inside `orders` array exists or not. But my code is giving error.

I have tried this one too.

```
$data = array(
'phone' => '516-425-5878',
"orders" => array(1891805481)
 );
```

But it returns empty results.

How do I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$in** operator selects documents where field values matches values in an array.

Please try executing following code snippet as a solution to above mentioned issue

```
$conn = new MongoClient('localhost:27017');
$db = $conn->selectDB("mydb");
$collection=$db->mycoll;
$data = array(
    'phone' => '516-425-5878',
    "orders" => array('$in'=>array('1891805481'))
);
$data=$collection->findOne($data);
```